# Java Thread.sleep/ Timer/ TimeUnit not working

Tags: java, swing, timer, paintcomponent, thread-sleep

I am having some trouble with a fun little side project of mine: What I am trying to achieve is a delay of some seconds in between the output of a string and therefore drawing one character (converted to String) at a time, in order to give the illusion of someone typing it (in a JFrame). However it seems like the for-loop (see below), first executes the total added time to wait and then draws the whole string at once, no matter which of the tried solutions i use (`try and catch + Thread.sleep`, `TimeUnit` or  `java.swing.timer` and `java.awt.timer`).
This is still one of my very first projects in java, so I do apologize if the code is a total mess. None of the pre-existing solutions on stackoverflow have helped me so far.
EDIT: The error message (probably unrelated) tells me by the way that the variable n should be declared final, because its scope isn't sufficient. This wouldn't work in this context.

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics maler) {
    super.paintComponent(maler);
    maler.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    maler.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
    maler.drawImage(bildchen, 37, 30, this);
    
    
    maler.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    maler.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
    maler.setColor(new Color(32, 194, 14));
    Font kram = new Font("OCR A Extended", Font.BOLD, 40);
    maler.setFont(kram);
    
    
    String text = "WILLKOMMEN!";
    final int  n = 0;
    int p = 90; 
    
    
    
    for (int i= 0; i<=10; i++) {
        
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                maler.drawString(Character.toString(text.charAt(n)), p, 200);
            }
        };
            
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 1000, 1000); 
         
        p = p+34;
        n++; 
        
        }
```

In this working part there still persists the problem that a) every characacter is displayed on the same spot instead of increasing x value; b) some characters are skipped over (or before they've been appearing in pairs of three). Here's the code:

```
AtomicInteger animationState = new AtomicInteger(0);
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics maler) {
    super.paintComponent(maler);
    maler.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    maler.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
    maler.drawImage(bildchen, 37, 30, this);
    
    
    maler.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    maler.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
    maler.setColor(new Color(32, 194, 14));
    Font kram = new Font("OCR A Extended", Font.BOLD, 40);
    maler.setFont(kram);
    
    int p = 90; 
    String text = "WILLKOMMEN!";
    maler.drawString(Character.toString(text.charAt(animationState.get())), p, 200);
    runAnimation();
}


        Timer timer = new Timer();
        

        void runAnimation() {
            TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    if (animationState.get(
                            ) < 11) {
                        animationState.incrementAndGet();
                        repaint();
                    } else {
                        cancel();
                    }
                }
            };
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 500, 500);
            
        
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you are trying to make an animation is fundamentally wrong, unfortunately.

For the right way to make an animation, you need to store the *current state* of the animation in some way, and make `paintComponent` use the state of the animation when it's painting.

In this case you're animating only the appearance of the text WILLKOMMEN, so the state you need is just a number: how many letters should be painted. An `AtomicInteger` object works well for this, so add an `AtomicInteger` instance variable, and use it from paintComponent:

```
AtomicInteger animationState = new AtomicInteger(0);

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics maler) {
    super.paintComponent(maler);
    String text = "WILLKOMMEN!";
    int p = 90;
    maler.drawString(text.substring(0, animationState.get()), p, 200);
}
```

To actually get the component to animate, you need to periodically change the animation state and make the component repaint itself. This can be done from a timer thread. In this case, you can call the `incrementAndGet` method to change animationState to animationState + 1, and then call the `repaint()` method to show the update state.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();

void runAnimation() {
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            if (animationState.get() < 10) {
                animationState.incrementAndGet();
                repaint();
            } else {
                cancel();
            }
        }
    };
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 1000, 1000);
}
```

When you want the animation to start, you call the `runAnimation` method.

Comment: thank you very much!, but why does it display several letters at a time? isn't animationState changing +1?

Comment: if you want one letter at a time use `text.charAt(animationState.get())` instead of `text.substring(0, animationState.get())`

Comment: ah thank you , but it doesn't seem to work. it does not compile

Comment: Yes, what you had originally in paintComponent also works. What's important is that the "current state" of the animation is captured in some way external to the `paintComponent` method, and that you update the state from outside the painting process.

Comment: no it throws this error message : `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method drawString(String, int, int) in the type Graphics is not applicable for the arguments (char)

 at Informatik.Timezones.paintComponent(Timezones.java:134)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)` it does actually compile but i see a blank screen

Comment: There's no `drawString` method that accepts a `char`. You have to convert the `char` to a `String`.

Comment: yes but now another error pops up, charat itself needs an integer argument: `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method charAt(int) is undefined for the type Timezones

 at Informatik.Timezones.paintComponent(Timezones.java:134)`

Comment: That error says you are trying to call the `charAt` method on something called "Timezones" . I would guess you are using the wrong variable.

Comment: Timezones is the class in which everything is contained. Where am I calling the text String in the first place? or rather, where should I call it?

Comment: Did you replace `text.charAt` with something else?

Comment: oh yes:) i removed it, although now my conversion to string with `Character.toString` doesn't work

Comment: To get the text to move, set the position based on the state of the animation. For example `int p = 30*animationState.get()`. Don't call `runAnimation()` from paintComponent: that will schedule a new animation every time the component is painted, which will have the effect of accelerating the animation. Call `runAnimation()` only once. It could be from an event handler when a button is clicked, or when you are making the frame visible.

Comment: done, i figured out the first thing in the meantime and by moving runAnimation() outside paintcomponent everything is correct except for the fact that the drawn letters disappear as soon as the next one is visible.

Comment: If your paintComponent draws only one letter, that one letter is all you'll see. If you want to see multiple letters, you need to draw multiple letters

Comment: but I thought I was printing the whole "Willkommen"-String

Comment: `text.charAt` returns one single character

Comment: yes, yes but I cannot remove it. Maybe I didn't exlpain it decently but I intended to display one character after another, not one character at a time.

Comment: in other words: i want to keep the old string and merely add a new one.there should be a way with repaint but I have no idea

Comment: Then use the substring method. You want to draw the string from the start until a position - text.substring(0, position) returns that string.

Comment: You should be using a Swing Timer, not a java.util.Timer.